# Common pattern for selecting more than one item in one go

Tags: multi-selection

I was wondering if there is a pattern out there that that allows the user to select multiple items in one go. Like I have shown in the example below. The selections could be either single items, or multi items.

The reason they are bound together is because they fall under the same group, and I would like the user to select the items with just a single click rather than a multi item drop down list.

I would be greateful for any advice on this front. Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think Google Data Studio's got a nice solution, part of material:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, XTOTHEL. However, I would am looking for a pattern which could have both brand and eybp-q3-2018 selectable in a single click.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hierarchical multiselect, like this example from google material:
[image]

This way, the user would be able to select the whole group or just the sub items.